# CKEditor converts input source

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have CKEditor on my web site. When I enter this code into source window:

```
<ul class="active">
   <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img align="" alt="" border="0" src="/media/1.png" /> 
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <span class="prec">from</span> 
            <span class="price">1</span>
        </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And then when I click Save it gets formatted to:

```
<ul class="active">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img align="" alt="" border="0" src="/media/1.png" /> </a>
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Headline</a></h3>
        <a href="#"><span class="prec">from</span> <span class="price">1</span> </a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to completely turn off code reformatting? It also changes some other html codes (flash on page, for example)

Can anybody give me some advice?

Comment: Are you sure "Headline" gets wrapped in an `<a>` tag?

Comment: yes. this is copy/paste from editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation on [formatting the HTML output](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting). [`CKEDITOR.htmlWriter`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.htmlWriter.html) handles the writing of source HTML. Its options are summarized in the docs. For example you can turn on breaking inside an `<a>` like this:

```
writer.setRules( 'a', {breakAfterOpen : true, breakBeforeClose: true} );
```

That way you should at least be able to get the editor to not put everything inside your anchors in one line.

However, I think you are looking for something like `sourceFormatting: none` but I doubt that this exists. The editor needs to parse your HTML for validation and its WYSIWYG functionality, so it seems to always get evaluated on save, stored formatless and re-written in the source window when it is opened.

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851068/prevent-ckeditor-from-formatting-code-in-source-mode) people try (mis-)using [`protectedSource`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource) to keep CKEditor off their HTML, but I did not try that.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that your input HTML is invalid. `<h3>` is a block-level element; it cannot appear inside an inline element like `<a>`. The browser cannot display this invalid HTML, so it's reformatting it to be valid (by duplicating the `<a>` tag), and CKEditor is just going along for the ride.

There's a little bit of extra reformatting being done around whitespace and newlines, but most of the changes you're seeing are related to this syntactical issue.

Comment: In html5 this is perfectly valid, which is why most users want to disable the reformat as it doesn't handle html5 yet.